# Bases de datos NoSQL Redis con .Net Framework

Tags: azure, azure-redis

Recientemente estoy trabajando con Azure Redis Cache y me preguntaba si existe algo por parte del .NET Framework para trabajar desde C# este tipo de bases de datos, algún tipo de API o parecido.

Veo que existen diversas formas de trabajar con Redis: strings, sets, etc.

Gracias por su atención.

http://redis.io/

Comment: Lo más acertado es lo que comenta gparis : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente como lo comentas. Existen varias maneras de almacenar información con Azure Redis Cache, normalmente son listas tipo KeyValue o Dictionary como también se les llama. En mis repositorios de GitHub puedes encontrar varios proyectos con Azure Redis Cache usando el .net Framework

https://github.com/vemoreno/AzureRedisCacheBitMaps

https://github.com/vemoreno/AzureRedisCacheHashes

https://github.com/vemoreno/AzureRedisCacheLists

https://github.com/vemoreno/AzureRedisCacheOrderSets

https://github.com/vemoreno/AzureRedisCacheSets

No olvides agregar la referencia StackExchange.Redis desde Nuget-Package

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Tus códigos me están ayudando mucho, es lo que necesitaba. Mil gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Hay [varios clientes](http://redis.io/clients#c) para C#.

Redis recomienda estos dos:

- [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)
- [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)

Answer (score 1):

También no hay que olvidar que existe una implementación de [OutputCache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-asp.net-output-cache-provider/) y [SessionState](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-asp.net-session-state-provider/) sobre Azure Redis.

Comment: Gracias Matías!

Answer (score 0):

Además si empleas **.NET Core** puedes usar la librería "*ServiceStack.Redis.StrongName*" o "*Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core*".

Saludos.